# events and self referencing components vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have commenting system which allows 1 level thread. Meaning 1st level comment will look like 
{
  ...content,
  thread: []
}
where thread may have more comments in it. I though this is good for self-referencing component and List with Slots. 
But after a while I do not know how to wire this thing up.

SingleComment component is given below

```
<template>
...  *content*

<b-button
    v-if="isCommentDeletable"
    @click="handleDelete"
</b-button>

<div v-for="item in item.thread" :key="item._id">
    <SingleComment class="ml-3"
        :item="item"
    />
</div>
</template>
...

    methods: {
        handleDelete () {
            this.$emit('remove')
        },
    }
... 
    components: {
        'NewComment': NewComment, 'SingleComment': this
    },
    name: 'SingleComment'
}
</script>
```

List component classic list is recieving array of items as prop and is given by

```
<div v-for="item in items" ...
    <slot
        name="listitem"
        :item="item"
    />
</div>
```

and this is the parent where I want to use these two components with modal 
Parent

```
<AppModal

>
...
<List
    class="my-1"
    :items="comments.docs"
>

    <template v-slot:listitem="{ item }">
        <SingleComment
            :item="item"
            :remove="removeItem"
            @remove="removeItem"
        />
    </template>
</List>
```

I want to wire this thing up in Parent so I can use single modal for whole list.
Do I wire thins thing up with events? Or? Any sort of help is welcome. I am stuck. I can make some hacks but I really do not know how to deal with this self referencing components.

Comment: my current thought is to pass function from the Parent as prop to the child and then i'd repeat that process in the deeper nested child.

```<SingleComment :item="item" :remove="removeItem" /> ```

Basically do the following twice. Is there another way?

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I'm having some trouble visualizing your whole setup. Could you post a link to the code on GitHub, CodeSandbox, etc?

Comment: hi @chipit24 thank you for answer. 
https://github.com/tomisicm/foody_app/blob/dev/src/components/CommentSection.vue link to the parent component

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one level of nesting, you could simply pass the component itself as a slot, like so:

```html
<Comment v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id" v-bind="comment">
  <Comment v-for="thread in comment.thread" :key="thread.id" v-bind="thread" />
</Comment>
```

Then you will only have to worry about passing props one level deep, as if you only had a single list of comments. I created an example of this on CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-mq24e.

---

If you want to use a recursive approach, you'll just have to pass props and events around; there's no magic solution that steps around this. Update CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-doy66.

You could avoid explicitly passing the `removeitem` event listener down by having a `removeitem` action on your Vuex store that you map to your component.

My opinion here, is that simpler is better, and you don't need recursion for one level of nesting. Put yourself in the shoes of a future developer and make the code easy to read and reason about; that future developer may even be you when you haven't looked at the codebase in a few weeks.